# PHP: replace date with string

Tags: php, string, date, replace, compare

I have a string containing **multiple** dates (from - to), separated by "|", example:

```
10.10.-29.10.2011 | 1.11.-31.11.2011
```

I need a code that will compare the newest start ("from") date (in this case 1.11.2011) and if this date is older than current date, then replace whole string with "CLOSED". 
Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: So 10.10.-29.10.2011 would be Oct 10, 2011 - Oct 29, 2011?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$dates = "10.10.-29.10.2010 | 13.8.-31.11.2011 | 14.8.-31.12.2011";
$datesArr = explode(" | ",$dates);
foreach($datesArr as $k=>$date) {
    $split = explode(".-",$date);
    $from = explode(".",$split[0]); $to = explode(".",$split[1]);
    $from = $from[0].".".$from[1].".".$to[2];
    if(strtotime($from)<time()) unset($datesArr[$k]);
}
if(!empty($datesArr)) {
    if(count($datesArr)==1) $dates = $datesArr[0];
    else {
        $dates = implode(" | ",$datesArr);
    }
}
else $dates = "CLOSED";
echo $dates;
```

Comment: Edited to what I believe is what you are looking for.

Comment: Excelent job! Works. One more little thingy... Can you modify a code to delete all old date range (including "|" after date) and leave only valid date and in case all dates are old then show message CLOSED?

Comment: There is something wrong.. this date: 10.10. - 29.10.2011 shows closed, but this date 16.9. - 29.9.2011 shows itself (two different pages)

Comment: Might be because you suddenly seem to have added a space between "." and "-". I have now updated the code to fulfill your second request.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it still doesnt work. If dates are older then today, it shows CLOSED, but newer dates shows nothing... I tried: old, old, new - shows nothing. Old, new, new - shows both new dates, correct. New, old, new - show both new, correct.

Comment: Problem is in $datesArr[0], which is empty, even though it should not be (because it should contain valid date). Dont know how to fix it